# implement console client signalR and self host signalR?

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr.client

I want connect a client to a self-hosted SignalR-server for notify console application from another console application.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem you're facing? Please clarify.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Combine this Self-Host guidance:
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-signalr-20-self-host
with this .Net client guidance:
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client
and you're mostly there.